# COUNTIFS on visible columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I have a problem with `COUNTIFS` and visible filter data.

I have data about different companies and the items that have been sent to them.
This data is stored in a separate worksheet.
On the main sheet I have `COUNTIFS` referencing the number of times we have sent a particular item to a particular company.
The `COUNTIFS` is as follows:

`=COUNTIFS('Cases '!$D:$D,C$2,'Cases '!$C:$C,$A3)`

In peudeo code it breaks down as:

`=COUNTIFS('Cases'ITEMCOLUMN, SEARCHITEM,'Cases 'COMPANYCOLUMN,SEARCHEDCOMPANY)`

Sometimes I want to filter the Cases worksheet based on some other criteria but I still need the main sheet to cross reference the number of times a company had been sent an item but now only based on the filtered results.

I have been pointed to the `SUBTOTAL` function but it is slightly incomprehensible and seems to only work for adding up filtered numbers.

Comment: how does COUNTIFS stop working when  you filter your sheet by some other criteria? COUNTIFS should not be affected, however SUBTOTAL for sure is affected.

Comment: Its not that the COUNTIF stops working its that the COUNTIF continues to counted the records that have been filtered out. For example a company can be sent 1 of 6 different packages and pay in different ways and this is stored in a data page where each package has a unique ID. On the main page there is a table that lists all companies in rows, along the columns are the different packages and the COUNTIFs reference the number of packages each company has been sent. The problem when I filter the data page by payment method I want the COUNTIFS to now only show the filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

A formula like this should work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    SUBTOTAL(
        3,
        OFFSET(
            Sheet2!$C$2:$C$4,
            ROW(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$4)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$4)),
            ,
            1)),
    --(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$4="a"),
    --(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$4="b"))
```

<sub>(indentation just for better understanding, hopefully)</sub>

For my data it works. I have some letters "a" in one column and some letters "b" in the other. The formula counts rows where both of "a" and "b" are present and the row is not filtered out.

Additional reading:
(1) http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/717624-subtotal-function-countif-sumif.html
(2) http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/how-to-use-countif-with-subtotal/de09fe89-6d98-4691-a25b-19b1a1e74bf2

Comment: Was the answer helpful?